# Conditional Probability -2 card

Tags: probability

Suppose you have two cards: one is painted yellow on both sides and the other is painted yellow on one side and red on the other You select a card at random and view one side.

You notice it is yellow. What is the probability the other side is yellow?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you share your own thoughts on the problem.  Tell us what you know, show what you have attempted, and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $YY$ denote the card which is yellow on both sides and $YR$ the one which is yellow on one side and red on the other.

We calculate the conditional probability $\mathbb{P}(YY|\textrm{observed one side yellow}) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(YY \textrm{ and observed one side yellow})}{\mathbb{P}(\textrm{observed one side yellow})}$

Note that $\mathbb{P}(YY \textrm{ and observed one side yellow}) = \frac{1}{2}$ since we select a card at random and $\mathbb{P}(\textrm{observed one side yellow}) = \frac{3}{4}$ since there are four sides of which three are yellow, so putting these facts together we get $$\mathbb{P}(YY|\textrm{observed one side yellow}) = \frac{2}{3}$$

Comment: thank you so much!